# using pg:push for Heroku in Windows 10

Tags: django, windows, heroku, postgis

I'm having issues trying to push a PostGIS database from my local machine to Heroku in Windows 10.

I think the problem has something to do with 'env', which can be set in Linux, etc.., but I'm unsure how to do it in Windows.

```
heroku pg:push MAPPPD DATABASE_URL --app mapppd
```

The above (where MAPPPD is my local Postgres/PostGIS database, and DATABASE_URL is my database on my Heroku app) only gives me:

```
DL is deprecated, please use Fiddle
'env' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. 
Password:
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "Grant"
!    Heroku client internal error.
!    Search for help at: https://help.heroku.com
!    Or report a bug at: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/issues/new

Error:       psql failed. exit status 512, output: "" (RuntimeError)
Command:     heroku pg:push MAPPPD DATABASE_URL --app mapppd
Plugins:     heroku-pg-transfer
Version:     heroku/toolbelt/3.42.25 (i386-mingw32) ruby/2.1.7
Error ID:    ee70861b921542ad939041602ddd9855
```

All the solutions I have come across are Linux based.

Also, it is trying to log me in as "Grant", when I want to log into my local db as "frontend"

Thanks in advance